# Selenium C#, loop until element is no longer visible question

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Using Selenium, C# etc on a seriews of tests and stuck on a particular problem
In 1 scenario a report is created and while the data is being created etc a spinner control is visible on the page. When the process is complete the spinner disapears.

I am wanting to loop until the spinner has gone, this can tyake between 30-180 seconds depending on amount of data and stress on test network.

I am using this code

```
new WebDriverWait(_driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(180)).Until(ExpectedConditions.InvisibilityOfElementLocated(spinner));
```

The logic stops at this point while the spinner is visible but when the spinner disapears then nothing happens. Waiting for elements to be visible is not a problem but it is waiting for elements to go.

What am I missing please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will use an arbitrary website to reproduce and solve your issue here:

```
const string Url = "https://the-internet.herokuapp.com/dynamic_loading/1";

using var driver = new ChromeDriver();

var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20))
{
    PollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(250)
};

driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(Url);

var startButton = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id = 'start']/button"));

wait.Until(driver => startButton.Displayed);
startButton.Click();

var loadingIndicator = driver.FindElement(By.Id("loading"));
wait.Until(driver => 
{
    // wait until progress bar to be hidden
    var displayed = !loadingIndicator.Displayed;

    // just for this demo to see in action what happens behind the scenes
    Console.WriteLine("---> " + displayed);
    return displayed;
});

var text = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id = 'finish']/h4")).Text;

Console.WriteLine(text);
```